# how to remove the unwanted white spaces between words without word break

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Is there any way to remove the unwanted white spaces between the words in a justified paragraph with out breaking the words? This is [my site](http://cochinchildhealth.com/). Please look in the two boxes about 2 doctors. Their paragraphs are not cleanly displayed. I tried so many methods but nothing works.

Comment: it seems you have problem with first doctor right ?

Comment: @SpiderCode: have pblm in both boxes sir.. in first everything is congested and in second spaces are not removing.. i gave both the same word-spacing and line height css..

Comment: seems it is not possible without using word break.

Comment: Agree with @SureshPonnukalai.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using following HTML code:

```
text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-word;
```

In general, full-justification on browsers makes text HARDER to read and should generally be avoided.

The above solution will work for IE only. But there is other way around. Try this:

```
.fulljustify {
  text-align: justify;
 }
.fulljustify:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: but sir..after i added this to the css of that boxes no changes appears... :( do u know what may be the reason?

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly. Now  it will work on other browsers as well.

Comment: `text-justify:inter-word;` will not work on other browsers except IE, so use other solution that I have provided.

Comment: no.. i hve inserted the same class and css in the 2nd doctor box.. but no changes.. can u plz look into my site?

Comment: I have seen your site. As I said, full justification generally be avoided. In your site there is a gap between `of     Paediatric     &` in one line and in next line first word is `Congenital Heart`. Now, even if you managed to reduce the gap between the words in first line, there is no space left to accommodate `Congenital` in the first line. Hence, there will be a gap. The only thing that can work is if you increase the width. Justification is hard when the width of the line is small.

Comment: ohh... okay... i cant increase the width..so u r saying the only way is width break ryt..? :(

Comment: Yes. Word break is the way.